# PHP function fires for all buttons instead of one

Tags: php

```
<button 
    id="add_to_litebox" 
    class="btn btn-success pull-right" 
    onClick='document.write("<?php add( id ) ?>");'>
Add 
</button>
```

**PHP Function :**

```
<?php
     function add( $id )
     {
      $My_DB_Obj->add();
     }
?>
```

In the above code, I am firing a php function which will insert into database using the "id" passed as parameter. **This Button is in LOOP. (using PHP)** (suppose it iterates 10 time )
Now every time, I click on the button, it calls the function 10 times with all the IDs.
(1 to 10) and insert into database 10 times

Comment: What's the question `?` Errors if any `?`

Comment: The function is being called for each button when I click on just 1...

Comment: Suppose, I click on 5th Button, It should write the respective entry to the database by passing id=5 to the function.

But it is calling the function for all Button's IDs and flooding the database...

Answer (score 0):

Function is not called when you `click` on the button but on display!

```
<?php add( id ) ?>
```

Line above is simply calling the function `add()`.

**Edit**

`PHP` is server side script, you can not access `PHP` from `HTML` or `JavaScript` as these are ran by your browser, not the server. What you can do is use `AJAX` call which is easy with [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/).

Comment: Ok. I got it.

So, what should I do to implement this ?

Comment: Ok. Thanx. I will try using AJAX.

Comment: I have tried AJAX. But, the function is only fires for the 1st button, not for the rest.

CODE : 
    $(document).ready(function(e) {
        $('#add_to_litebox').click( function() {
            $.post("AjaxDemo_src.php" , 
            {
                banner_id : 'sdc13002'
            } ,
            function(data)
           {
                $('#add_to_litebox').val(data);
            }
        );
       
    });
    });

Comment: Sorry, I don't know how to format code in comments...
@Linek